# PHP PDO/MySQL: Dropdown values from database table cannot be inserted to another table

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

I'm making a Helpdesk Ticket System. There seems to be a problem inserting data from a dropdown with values selected from a database table column to a database table. I'm using PHP PDO with MySQL.

My select dropdown looks like this:

[Dropdown picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWdMV.png)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Department <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        <select class="form-control" name="department" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected></option>
            <?php
                $department_query = "SELECT * FROM department";
                $stmt = $db->prepare($department_query);
                $stmt->execute();
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                echo "<option value='".$row['$department']."''>".$row['department']."</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

It can already read and display the data `department_name` on the dropdown options.

For inserting the values from my form, it can already insert other values EXCEPT values from the dropdown.

My inline php code for inserting is:

```
<?php 
          if(isset($_POST['addticket'])){
            $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ticket (requestor_name, employee_name, department_concern, subject, description, priority) VALUES (:Requestor, :Employee, :Department, :Subject, :Description, :Priority)");
            $stmt->bindParam(':Requestor', $Requestor);
            $stmt->bindParam(':Employee', $Employee);
            $stmt->bindParam(':Department', $Department);
            $stmt->bindParam(':Subject', $Subject);
            $stmt->bindParam(':Description', $Description);
            $stmt->bindParam(':Priority', $Priority);

            $Requestor = $_POST['requestor'];
            $Employee = $_POST['employee'];
            $Department = $_POST['department'];
            $Subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $Description = $_POST['description'];
            $Priority = $_POST['priority'];
            $stmt->execute();

          }
        ?>
```

There wasn't any error but it the value of the select dropdown is not inserted in my database, while other values are inserted. See picture below.

[Database Result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgou4.png)

I have tried changing the `name=""`, `$_POST['']` hundreds of times - still same result and I couldn't find the answer.

All I want is to display the

```
"<option value='".$row['$department']."''>".$row['department']."</option>"
```

from

```
<select class="form-control" name="department" required>
```

to

```
$Department = $_POST['department'];
```

so that it may be inserted into my database.

It would be great if anyone can help me. Please. 
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: echo '<option value="'.$row['$department'].'"'>'.$row['department'].'</option>';   copy and paste this it should solve it ,also remove this <option value="" disabled selected></option>

Comment: @Gert - still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="" disabled selected></option>
```

Remove disabled from your option

Comment: it still doesn't display the value in the dropdown